# How can I use comm in this way?

Tags: bash, comm

From my understanding I want to use `comm -23 file1 file2`. file1 is the result of `find` and file2 is `cut -c43- list`. Is it possible I can write this as 1 line and not use any files (except the one I have named list)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Process substitution is your friend here:

```
$ comm -23 <(find /dir -name 'something') <(cut -c43- list)
```

The format `<(command)` applies a temp file descriptor to the `command` and the whole `<( )` is used as a file input to `comm` (or any other command).
See [more about process substitution here](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/proc_subst) . Also check `man bash` :

> Process Substitution
>          Process substitution allows a process's input or output to be referred to using a filename.  It takes the form of <(list) or >(list).  The  process  list  is
>          run asynchronously, and its input or output appears as a filename.  This filename is passed as an argument to the current
>   command as the result of the expansion.  If the >(list) form is used, writing to the file will provide input for list.  If the <(list) form is used, the file passed
>   as an argument  should  be
>          read to obtain the output of list.  Process substitution is supported on systems that support named pipes (FIFOs) or the /dev/fd
>   method of naming open files.

Comment: @acidzombie24 Welcome. I am sure you know what to do when questions got answered :-)

Comment: I absolutely do but the site doesn't always allow me to immediately accept something ;D